# VBA For loop performance

Tags: vba, excel

I wonder if by doing so:

```
For a = Start_row To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 1
```

will imply that everytime the execution checks the `For` loop condition, it will have to recalculate the `Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count` statement. Maybe it is stored in the memory the first time?

Comment: I would not iterate over any Range anyway. Get a copy of the sheets data into an array and work with this. It'll likely be significant faster.

Comment: No it will remain static based on the first loop.  If the count returns 300 the first time it will always be 300 until the For loop ends at start_row.

Comment: Ok thanks Scott. Very helpful. pinxto: nice workarround also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the end of the `For` loop is evaluated only at the beginning.

Besides, be aware that the `UsedRange`:

- does not necessarily start at the first row
- does not necessarily end at the last non-empty row